# Bootstrap popover content via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i have a next code about popover, it works fine with content, but popovers doesn't create. is all ok with this code?

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(answer) {
            $(element).popover({
                container: 'body',
                html: true,
                content: function (answer) {
                    return answer;
                }
            });
            $(element).popover('show')
        },
    })
```

element is A tag. and answer is html as string.
When it comes to popover part looks like nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set value to content directly. Not a function.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(answer) {
            $(element).popover({
                container: 'body',
                html: true,
                content: answer
            });
            $(element).popover('show')
        },
    })
```